# Hidden and visible surface rendering in javascript by overlapping colours

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas, rendering, zbuffer

I am trying to implement a hidden surface determination algorithm in my 3D renderer. I have found very good approaches, such as Z-Buffer or Warnock's algorithm. However, they are extremely resource-consuming. Thus I wondered, Why not use opaque overlapping colours, with which I could get the same visual results?. I would like to receive some feedback an opinions before going further, and in case it turns out to be a good solution, of course, to use this post as a way of sharing it with the community. The method would basically come down to: 1) Ordering all polygons in the scene by their Z coordinate 2)Rendering all of them in order, using opaque colours. The image/view/visual effect would be the same, without having to resort to a costly pixel-by-pixel computational process. 
(Example: say I have two intersecting polygons (P1, P2). Given that the viewer's closest Z coordinate is 0, if P1z=10 and P2z=3, then the rendering order would be: P2>P1. When drawn, P2's colour will cover those P1's edges and colours placed in the 2D-XY-intersection between the two polygons ) What cons do you think this could have? Do you think that it would suffice the problem? 
PS: I do not use polygonal meshes,  the 3D-objects to be processed are simple convex and concave figures.

Answer (score 0):

Polygons can intersect (even partially) and determine what part of one polygon is in front of the other it's a very expensive computation.

Comment: That would not really be a problem in the context of my program though. Anyway, it would still be way faster than a z- buffer. I have found on google that 'my' idea already exists actually. It is called the "painter's algorithm". The only thing that concerns me now is the problem of " Cyclic overlapping", which would affect my program, only if this phenomenon occurs in the same, nonself-intersecting, 3D object.

Comment: z-buffer normally is executed on GPU because, as you said, it is really cumbersome. To my knowledge, the only way to resolve your problem is to split every polygon with every else and keep only the leftovers closer to the observer. [Occlusion culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-surface_determination#Occlusion_culling) may help to skip complex hidden objects from the computation.